# How to call datepicker Jquery plugin in Page onload using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a jquery plugin, I want to call this on page onload event. I have tried with below code. someone help me on this. Thanks.

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        app.element(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("#req_date").glDatePicker();
        });

        $scope.AddCrims = function () {

            alert('hi');
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `angular` not `app`:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("#req_date").glDatePicker();
});
```

Comment: i have changed to angular that also not working @michelem